# Adding attributes to customer entity

Tags: php, magento, custom-attributes

my current goal is to add a new customer attribute (with `int` type) which should appear as select with predefined options (loaded from a model with entries editable in backend, which is done).
I'm struggling with proper use of `$installer->addAttribute()` method, especially specifying correct source option. Other problem is the new attribute isn't saved to eav_entity_attribute table

I'm on Magento CE 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is the code for a basic `int` attribute with `text` renderer:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'Some textual description',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
 $entityTypeId,
 $attributeSetId,
 $attributeGroupId,
 'your_attribute_code_here',
 '999'  //sort_order
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$oAttribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();
```

The unusual step for adding attributes is the `setData('used_in_forms')` this seems to be unique to customer attributes.  Without it, the field won't get rendered, certainly not in the adminhtml anyway.  You can see the valid options for this array in the `customer_form_attribute` database table.

In terms of using a `select` with predefined options, this is what you need:

```
$iAttributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'your_attribute_code_here');
$aClasses = array('TV','DVD','Home Theatre','Air Conditioner','Stereo/Hifi','Game Console','Camcorder','VCR','Set Top Box','PVR');
$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $iAttributeId;

for($iCount=0;$iCount<sizeof($aClasses);$iCount++){
    $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $aClasses[$iCount];
}
$setup->addAttributeOption($aOption);
```

And here is a [walk-through](http://subesh.com.np/2010/01/creating-custom-sourced-multiselect-product-attribute/) on using a custom source for your drop-down

Hope this helps,
JD

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will be giving this a try. As for predefined options they should not be static in my case but editable from admin interface, that's why I was trying to make use of `source` option

Comment: Edited with link for dynamic options.  My example of predefined options are editable in the admin if you are using a version of Magento that provides the Customer Attribute Manager, it's just a starting set.

Comment: Just tried your code and its worked like a charm, addAttributeToGroup call was really helpful. Also I set up the source option.

Comment: But now I've got different problem - the attribute value is not saved from registration form to `customer_entity_int` table, although I have `<fieldsets>` set up for `<customer_account>` for my attribute name. On the other side should the new attribute appear on the registration form or additional coding required? I use custom block injected using `getChildHtml` but this feels wrong. Hope this not out of scope for my initial question

Comment: @zifius - it would be easier to answer if you ask a separate question.  If you can see your attribute installed as you desire, mark this as accepted and we'll try to answer the next one. Cheers, JD

Comment: Ok, just did that, thanks again for clear answer. Best regards, Alex

Comment: **Attention with sort_order:**
With code like that I always got sort_order = 0 in the DB, it took me some hours of debugging to see why:
addAttributeToGroup() works fine but $oAttribute->save() overwrites the sort_order again, actually it executed the following queries:
`INSERT INTO customer_form_attribute (form_code,attribute_id) VALUES('adminhtml_customer',159);
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute SET sort_order = 0 WHERE (attribute_id='159')`
**Solution:**
Set sort_order before saving the attribute instead:
`$oAttribute->setData('sort_order', $sortOrder);`

Comment: Thanks @Fabian, I've noticed the sorting issue but didn't bother to check why it was happening as everything else worked

Comment: If you need help knowing how to add this setup information to your install then I recommend using this post: http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here');

keeps returning a Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute vs a Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Attribute object.  it looks the same, just has a different attribute code.  any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I was getting the following error on Magento Enterprise 1.12 on the server. It worked fine on localhost. Had become a nightmare.
After I removed
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

everything worked fine. I changed it to:
$setup = $this;
$setup->startSetup();

------------------------------
Install Error: exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /var/www/vhosts/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 139' in /var/www/vhosts/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245

Comment: @JonathanDay you are executing `$installer->startSetup();` but then at the end `$setup->endSetup();` ???

Answer (score 23):

@[Jonathan Day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962237/3765)'s answer is great and helped me tremendously. However - as long as you've set your `setup` class to `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`, then Magento can do all of that work for you:

```
<!-- config.xml Example -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <acme_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Acme_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </acme_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here is the `mysql4-install-X.X.X.php` file:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    'customer',
    'acme_imported',
    array(
        'group'                => 'Default',
        'type'                 => 'int',
        'label'                => 'Imported into Acme',
        'input'                => 'select',
        'source'               => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'global'               => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'required'             => 0,
        'default'              => 0,
        'visible_on_front'     => 1,
        'used_for_price_rules' => 0,
        'adminhtml_only'       => 1,
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The `adminhtml_only` above will handle all of the `used_in_forms` logic for you. Also, defining `group` will take care of assigning it to the attribute group.

Comment: Using 1.7.0.2 CE, the *adminhtml_only* trick didn't work for me. I still had to add: `Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )->getAttribute( 'customer', $custom_attribute_id )->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )->save()` for the attribute to show up in the backend.

Answer (score 4):

Just you have add your customer attribute under by your custom module mysql setup file through the following script.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "yourattributename",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Bad Customer",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "yourattributename");
```

The following script used for where want to use customer attribute

```
$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 0)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provide by **alex and leek** both worked for me.
Only I have to add the setter function in our AccountController.php

```
$customer->setProfession($this->getRequest()->getPost('profession')) 
                        ->save(); // Added for updating Profession
```

Where "profession" was my custom attribute.