# Magento - Add attribute to customer entity

Tags: magento, attributes, entity, magento-1.9

For two days I have been trying to **add new customer attribute** to the magento database. But it isn't working. I added a simple `nickname` input field to the `register.phtml` and `edit.phtml` following this tutorial:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields

Here is the inherent forum post:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9620/

The attribute is added to the database table `eav_attribute`, but the value doesn't appear in the `customer_entity_varchar`.

---

### Here is what I have:

All files are located under `app/code/local/Company/`

---

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/etc/config.xml**

(watch out for: `<!-- nickname -->`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Customer>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_dataflow>
                <store_id><system>1</system></store_id>
                <store><ignore>1</ignore></store>
                <entity_id><system>1</system><ignore>1</ignore></entity_id>
                <attribute_set_id><system>1</system><ignore>1</ignore></attribute_set_id>
                <attribute_set><ignore>1</ignore></attribute_set>
                <entity_type_id><system>1</system></entity_type_id>
                <increment_id><system>1</system><ignore>1</ignore></increment_id>
                <parent_id><system>1</system></parent_id>
                <created_at><system>1</system></created_at>
                <updated_at><system>1</system></updated_at>
                <group_id><ignore>1</ignore></group_id>
                <type_id><system>1</system><ignore>1</ignore></type_id>
                <type><ignore>1</ignore></type>
                <created_in><system>1</system><ignore>1</ignore></created_in>
                <website_id><system>1</system></website_id>
                <default_billing><system>1</system></default_billing>
                <default_shipping><system>1</system></default_shipping>
 
                <prefix><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><mapped>1</mapped></prefix>
                <firstname><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><required>1</required><mapped>1</mapped></firstname>
                <middlename><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><mapped>1</mapped></middlename>
                <lastname><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><required>1</required><mapped>1</mapped></lastname>
                <suffix><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><mapped>1</mapped></suffix>
                <street_full><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></street_full>
                <street1><street>1</street></street1>
                <street2><street>1</street></street2>
                <street3><street>1</street></street3>
                <street4><street>1</street></street4>
                <street5><street>1</street></street5>
                <street6><street>1</street></street6>
                <street7><street>1</street></street7>
                <street8><street>1</street></street8>
                <city><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></city>
                <region><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></region>
                <country><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><billing_required>1</billing_required><shipping_required>1</shipping_required></country>
                <postcode><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping><billing_required>1</billing_required><shipping_required>1</shipping_required></postcode>
                <telephone><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></telephone>
                <company><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></company>
                <fax><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></fax>
                <mobile><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></mobile>
                <!-- nickname -->
                <nickname><system>1</system></nickname>
            </customer_dataflow>
        </fieldsets>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <prefix><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></prefix>
                <firstname><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></firstname>
                <middlename><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></middlename>
                <lastname><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></lastname>
                <suffix><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></suffix>
                <email><create>1</create><update>1</update></email>
                <password><create>1</create></password>
                <confirmation><create>1</create></confirmation>
                <dob><create>1</create><update>1</update></dob>
                <taxvat><create>1</create><update>1</update></taxvat>
                                 <!-- nickname -->
                <nickname><create>1</create><update>1</update></nickname>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
 
        <customer>
            <address>
                <formats>
                    <text translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Text</title>
                        <defaultFormat><![CDATA[
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
{{var street1}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
{{depend city}}{{var city}},  {{/depend}}{{depend region}}{{var region}}, {{/depend}}{{var postcode}}
{{var country}}
T: {{var telephone}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend mobile}}M: {{var mobile}}{{/depend}}
                        ]]></defaultFormat>
                    </text>
                    <oneline translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Text One Line</title>
                        <htmlEscape>true</htmlEscape>
                        <defaultFormat>
<![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}, {{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}]]>
                        </defaultFormat>
                    </oneline>
                    <html translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>HTML</title>
                        <htmlEscape>true</htmlEscape>
                        <defaultFormat><![CDATA[
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{var street1}}<br />
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend city}}{{var city}},  {{/depend}}{{depend region}}{{var region}}, {{/depend}}{{var postcode}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend mobile}}<br/>M: {{var mobile}}{{/depend}}
            ]]></defaultFormat>
                    </html>
                    <pdf translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>PDF</title>
                        <defaultFormat><![CDATA[
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{var street1}}|
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend city}}{{var city}},  {{/depend}}{{depend region}}{{var region}}, {{/depend}}{{var postcode}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend mobile}}<br/>M: {{var mobile}}{{/depend}}|
            ]]></defaultFormat>
                    </pdf>
                    <js_template template="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Javascript Template</title>
                        <defaultFormat><![CDATA[#{prefix} #{firstname} #{middlename} #{lastname} #{suffix}<br/>#{company}<br/>#{street0}<br/>#{street1}<br/>#{street2}<br/>#{street3}<br/>#{city}, #{region}, #{postcode}<br/>#{country_id}<br/>T: #{telephone}<br/>F: #{fax}<br/>M: #{mobile}]]></defaultFormat>
                    </js_template>
                </formats>
            </address>
        </customer>
        <models>
            <customer_entity>
                <rewrite>
                    <setup>Company_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</setup>
                </rewrite>
            </customer_entity>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customer_setup>
                <rewrite>
                    <setup>Company_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</setup>
                </rewrite>
            </customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Company/Customer/Model/Entity/Setup.php**

(watch out again for: `/* nickname */`)

```php
class Company_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup{
            
    public function getDefaultEntities()
        {
            return array(
                'customer' => array(
                    'entity_model'          =>'customer/customer',
                    'table'                 => 'customer/entity',
                    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
                    'increment_per_store'   => false,
                    'additional_attribute_table' => 'customer/eav_attribute',
                    'entity_attribute_collection' => 'customer/attribute_collection',
                    'attributes' => array(
    //                    'entity_id'         => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'entity_type_id'    => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'attribute_set_id'  => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'increment_id'      => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'created_at'        => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'updated_at'        => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'is_active'         => array('type'=>'static'),
    
                        'website_id' => array(
                            'type'          => 'static',
                            'label'         => 'Associate to Website',
                            'input'         => 'select',
                            'source'        => 'customer/customer_attribute_source_website',
                            'backend'       => 'customer/customer_attribute_backend_website',
                            'sort_order'    => 10,
                        ),
                        'store_id' => array(
                            'type'          => 'static',
                            'label'         => 'Create In',
                            'input'         => 'select',
                            'source'        => 'customer/customer_attribute_source_store',
                            'backend'       => 'customer/customer_attribute_backend_store',
                            'visible'       => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 20,
                        ),
                        'created_in' => array(
                            'type'          => 'varchar',
                            'label'         => 'Created From',
                            'sort_order'    => 30,
                        ),
                        'prefix' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Prefix',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 37,
                        ),
                        'firstname' => array(
                            'label'         => 'First Name',
                            'sort_order'    => 40,
                        ),
                        'middlename' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Middle Name/Initial',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 43,
                        ),
                        'lastname' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Last Name',
                            'sort_order'    => 50,
                        ),
                        'suffix' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Suffix',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 53,
                        ),
                        'email' => array(
                            'type'          => 'static',
                            'label'         => 'Email',
                            'class'         => 'validate-email',
                            'sort_order'    => 60,
                        ), /* nickname */
                        'nickname' => array(
                            'label'         => 'nickname',
                            'unique'        => true,
                            'sort_order'    => 65,
                            'required'      => true,
                        ),
                        'group_id' => array(
                            'type'          => 'static',
                            'input'         => 'select',
                            'label'         => 'Group',
                            'source'        => 'customer/customer_attribute_source_group',
                            'sort_order'    => 70,
                        ),
                        'dob' => array(
                            'type'          => 'datetime',
                            'input'         => 'date',
                            'backend'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'label'         => 'Date Of Birth',
                            'sort_order'    => 80,
                        ),
                        'password_hash' => array(
                            'input'         => 'hidden',
                            'backend'       => 'customer/customer_attribute_backend_password',
                            'required'      => false,
                        ),
                        'default_billing' => array(
                            'type'          => 'int',
                            'visible'       => false,
                            'required'      => false,
                            'backend'       => 'customer/customer_attribute_backend_billing',
                        ),
                        'default_shipping' => array(
                            'type'          => 'int',
                            'visible'       => false,
                            'required'      => false,
                            'backend'       => 'customer/customer_attribute_backend_shipping',
                        ),
                        'taxvat' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Tax/VAT Number',
                            'visible'       => true,
                            'required'      => false,
                        ),
                        'confirmation' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Is Confirmed',
                            'visible'       => false,
                            'required'      => false,
                        ),
                        'created_at' => array(
                            'type'          => 'static',
                            'label'         => 'Created At',
                            'visible'       => false,
                            'required'      => false,
                            'input'         => 'date',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
    
                'customer_address'=>array(
                    'entity_model'  =>'customer/customer_address',
                    'table' => 'customer/address_entity',
                    'additional_attribute_table' => 'customer/eav_attribute',
                    'entity_attribute_collection' => 'customer/address_attribute_collection',
                    'attributes' => array(
    //                    'entity_id'         => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'entity_type_id'    => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'attribute_set_id'  => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'increment_id'      => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'parent_id'         => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'created_at'        => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'updated_at'        => array('type'=>'static'),
    //                    'is_active'         => array('type'=>'static'),
    
                        'prefix' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Prefix',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 7,
                        ),
                        'firstname' => array(
                            'label'         => 'First Name',
                            'sort_order'    => 10,
                        ),
                        'middlename' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Middle Name/Initial',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 13,
                        ),
                        'lastname' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Last Name',
                            'sort_order'    => 20,
                        ),
                        'suffix' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Suffix',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 23,
                        ),
                        'company' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Company',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 30,
                        ),
                        'street' => array(
                            'type'          => 'text',
                            'backend'       => 'customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_street',
                            'input'         => 'multiline',
                            'label'         => 'Street Address',
                            'sort_order'    => 40,
                        ),
                        'city' => array(
                            'label'         => 'City',
                            'sort_order'    => 50,
                        ),
                        'country_id' => array(
                            'type'          => 'varchar',
                            'input'         => 'select',
                            'label'         => 'Country',
                            'class'         => 'countries',
                            'source'        => 'customer_entity/address_attribute_source_country',
                            'sort_order'    => 60,
                        ),
                        'region' => array(
                            'backend'       => 'customer_entity/address_attribute_backend_region',
                            'label'         => 'State/Province',
                            'class'         => 'regions',
                            'sort_order'    => 70,
                        ),
                        'region_id' => array(
                            'type'          => 'int',
                            'input'         => 'hidden',
                            'source'        => 'customer_entity/address_attribute_source_region',
                            'required'      => 'false',
                            'sort_order'    => 80,
                            'label'         => 'State/Province'
                        ),
                        'postcode' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Zip/Postal Code',
                            'sort_order'    => 90,
                        ),
                        'telephone' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Telephone',
                            'sort_order'    => 100,
                        ),
                        'fax' => array(
                            'label'         => 'Fax',
                            'required'      => false,
                            'sort_order'    => 110,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }   
}
```

**app/design/frontend/default/company/template/customer/form/register.phtml**

```
<label for="nickname" class="required" style="margin-left: -1px;"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Nickname') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getnickname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Nickname') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

i also run this piece of php code in the top of **register.phtml** to add the attribute to the **eav_attribute**
this code was executed once:

```
<?php
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $AttrCode = 'nickname';
    $settings = array (
        'position' => 1,
        'is_required' => 0
    );
    $setup->addAttribute('1', $AttrCode, $settings);
?>
```

**app/design/frontend/default/company/template/customer/form/edit.phtml**

```
<label for="nickname" class="required" style="margin-left: -1px;"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Nickname') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getnickname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Nickname') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

I also manually cleared the **/var/cache** folder but without any effect.

I have no idea what else I could do, so any help is very welcome.

**EDIT:**

Ok here is what i have tried on the magento root:

```
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
set_time_limit (0);
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'nickname', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Nickname',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 1,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
 $entityTypeId,
 $attributeSetId,
 $attributeGroupId,
 'nickname',
 '999'  //sort_order
);


$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'nickname');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));

$oAttribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

This code will be executed fine and there is no error message or something but also no new attribute added to the **eav_attribute** table.

Comment: Over time, your pasted links will expire and other people won't be able to use your post to solve their own problem. Please edit your post and just inline the relevant sections of code in the post, as you did with your setup file.

Comment: @joseph-mastey You're right, but I've tried to add the whole code andit was cutted and no longer fully, thats why I used the mysticpaste. But, I'll try it again.

Comment: @joseph-mastey I added the Setup.php above but the conversion of the xml-code does not work properly, it will omit the second half of the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding attributes to customer entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity)

Comment: did you solved your problem? if yes, I d like to know how because I am stuck with a similar case. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I edited your script and it worked fine for me, I can see new attribute in backed now.

Replace this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
```

With this:

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->startSetup();
```