# Magento - attribute "input-type" checkbox

Tags: magento, input, attributes, checkbox

I have seen a similar question but I did not find an answer there :
[How can I get my custom backend Magento Customer Checkbox Attribute to save my selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114099/how-can-i-get-my-custom-backend-magento-customer-checkbox-attribute-to-save-my-s?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'tip', array(
    'group'         => 'ISM',
    'input'         => 'checkbox',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'TIP',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 0,
    'filterable' => 0,
    'comparable'    => 0,
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'global'        => 1,
    'used_in_product_listing' => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1
));
```

I have created an attribute, but it doesn't save the value when I edit-save or create-save the product.

Comment: `'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'` can be used only with `'input' => 'select'`.

Comment: what use  to   'input' => 'checkbox' ?

Comment: I don't know. Where did you get `'input' => 'checkbox'`? I can't found any product/category/customer attribute with such input type.

Comment: have you seen this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/adding-a-checkbox-attribute-to-customer-instead-of-multi-select

Answer (score 0):

Use 'input' as `int` because you always store the value of the checkbox '0' or '1'. And for source you are already using core options boolean that is 0 or 1.