# Magento - create a customer multiselect attribute

Tags: magento

How can I create a Multi-select attribute for customers ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding attributes to customer entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity)

Comment: It' not the same thing, with multiselect is more complex !

Comment: If you read the post, you will see that the second part of my answer shows you how to add attribute options for a select attribute, the code is the same for a multiselect.

Comment: That don't help too much

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this through module and create setup script.In setup script create attribute of type multiselect and follow this link for more and detail information.[Multi select attribute for customer](http://www.danneh.org/2010/03/adding-multi-select-attributes-using-an-installer-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this through a module, specifically through the setup script. I would read the following blog post from Alan Storm to get a better idea how they work.

http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources