# How to create a custom registration module in magento

Tags: magento, module, registration

I am new in magento. I want to create a custom registration module for seller in magento 1.5 or 1.6. There are needed two registration like one is general user, another seller. I don't know how magento's default registration module is built. I also don't know how to set up and how to connect between the form and the table like 'customer_entity_varchar' and other table.I think it follows MVC pattern like Joomla And also how to call the function from controller to model for writing "INSERT" sql query. If any one knows about it , please, guide me with giving links or doc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn about creating a Magento Module.

1. Create a Magento Module [Basics in Magento Module Development](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/)
2. Then you going to create an own registration controller for sellers.
3. Extend the customer entity by an attribute saying the customer status (seller|general) or use the Customer Groups [Adding Attributes to Customers Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237#5962237) (see for additional informations [About EAV Attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value))
4. add custom attributes to sellers like in step 3.

I hope could help you!

Comment: any link/help regarding step 2 and 3 will be appreciated