# Creating Catalog Input Type for Store Owner custom type - checkbox

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I would like to create checkbox field for "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" option for Magento attributes. I would like to have checkbox as a solution. What is the easiest way to do this right way, without any hardcoding filters.html?

Comment: I found this, but it looks like not complete answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237#5962237