# Magento : Custom database field not loading in collection

Tags: php, database, magento, collections, entity-attribute-value

Hi I've added two fields to the table 'customer_entity' through my module's setup script, which worked fine.

I can fetch and update the columns using direct sql in magento.

But when I load the customer collection like this-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('group_id',4); //->addFieldToFilter('is_company_admin',0);
```

The collection loads but when I add the commented part, it shows an error, maybe because the field is not a part of collection although it is a database field??

I tried this `->getSelect()->where("is_company_admin=0 and company_id={$current_company_id}")` after the collection but it does not work either.

So, How can I filter by custom fields in collection? Thanks

Comment: print the collection query and checks what you have got ?

Comment: try using array like `$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_company_admin', array('eq' => 0 ));`

Comment: @MagentoUser this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a strange system regarding the EAV entities.
In order to work properly, the columns in the main table (in your case `customer_entity`) need to have a static corresponding attribute. (all except `'entity_type_id', 'attribute_set_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'parent_id', 'increment_id'`).
So you need to add an attribute with code `is_company_admin`. [Here is how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962237/2047249)
.
The only difference is that the field `type` must have the value `static` if you added a column to the main table.
I recommend droping that column and just add `is_company_admin` just as an attribute following the tutorial in the link above.