# Installer Script gives me 'Wrong Entity ID' Magento error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following installer script - when I try to run this I get the following Magento error:

```
Error in file: "/vagrant/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/SS/Raptor/sql/raptor_setup/install-0.0.1.php" - Wrong entity ID
```

My installer script is as follows:

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
));

$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
));

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong setup class. You could use `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` to add the attributes this way. See this answer to [use Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup to add customer attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5962237/2455224).

Additional quote attributes require a different setup class. You can use `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup` as model here.

Answer (score 3):

Magento2 Fix:

You need to include your dependencies in your ModuleName/etc/module.xml file. I was adding a custom attribute for Products and had to include:

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
</sequence>
```

Comment: Hi @sianguish, I solved one issue with this, but then it appeared again in the  Magento-Downloadable module, which I didn't modify. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Just note. I have seen time and time again eav setup placed in the install/upgradeSchema files. The schema of the database is not changing here and therefore should properly be place in install/upgradeData scripts. The issue why you run into 'Wrong Entity ID' on installs is that the schema for the Magento_Catalog has been created but there is no data in the table which is why you get the error. Placing your code in the proper upgrade script solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to create attribute for two different entities use following code in config.xml

```
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
---
---
<resources>
    <namespace_module_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </namespace_module_setup>
</resources>
```

In Setup.php file write following code.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup
{

}
```

Then after create two separate installer & upgrade files

install-0.1.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php

```
$installer = $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');;

$installer->startSetup();

// now here write your code to create attribute 


$installer->endSetup();
```